# How many Swaminarayan sects/subsects are currently active?

Tags: sects, swaminarayan

someone says in Quora

> Entire Swaminarayan Smapraday is divided into around 45+ different sects.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Multiple subsets have emerged

> [New Swaminarayan Sects](https://web.archive.org/web/20201229174230/https://www.encyclopedia.com/environment/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/swaminarayan-movement)
>
> **As it happened, the greatest schism in the Swaminarayan movement was
> prompted not by outsiders but came from within. In 1906 a sādhu, Swami
> Yagnapurushdas, left the Vadtal temple. In 1907 he established the
> first new Swaminarayan sect, the Bochasanwasi Shri Akshar Purushottam
> Swaminarayan Sanstha (BAPS).** Headquartered in Ahmedabad, Gujarat, BAPS
> claims over one million followers worldwide including both laity and
> ascetics.
>
> .....
>
> More so than the original sect, BAPS is a global movement
> and, early on, it embraced new technologies to support its
> transnational growth. It runs a large...
>
> ...
>
> The wealthy BAPS
> organization is criticized by dam opponents for acting to protect its
> class interests, including those of its land holding members. In
> response, BAPS followers who are familiar with the Narmada controversy
> point to the various village relocation and community rehabilitation
> projects voluntarily instigated and funded by BAPS.
>
> **In addition to BAPS's break from the original Swaminarayan satsaṅg,
> other schisms have occurred. In 1966 a handful of East African BAPS
> followers broke away and founded the Yogi Divine Society.**
>
> **Additionally, sādhus from the original movement have left to form
> their own institutions** that sometimes (e.g., Swaminarayan Gurukuls)
> but not always (e.g., Swaminarayan Gadi) retain an affiliation with
> their gāddī.
>
> <sup>Kim, Hanna H. (2005), "Swaminarayan Movement", in Jones, Lindsay
> (ed.), Encyclopedia of Religion: 15-Volume Set, vol. 13 (2nd ed.),
> Detroit, Mi: MacMillan</sup>

So, indeed there are multiple subsects, a perfect count of which currently might be unfeasible, as such which are many.